# Update a single quoteLineItem based on the below condition

Tags: apex, controller, class, method

I need to update a single quoteLineItem, whenever a custom checkbox "PROMO" is checked, a custom field "Discount %" has to be filled in with "20" in the same quote line item. There can be several quoteLineItems but it has to update only that quoteLineItem which promo is checked. Below is the method that I have written but it's updating all quoteLineItems.

```
public PageReference UpdatePromo() {    
    for (integer i = 0; i < quoteLineItems.size(); i++) {
        for (integer index = i+1; index < quoteLineItems.size(); index++) {   
            if (quoteLineItems[i].quoteLineItem.Promo__c == true && quoteLineItems[i].quoteLineItem.Product_Code__c == 'LIC-OPTZ-01') {
                quoteLineItems[i].quoteLineItem.Discount = 20.00;
                quoteLineItems[i].quoteLineItem.Discount_Approved__c = true;
            } else {
               quoteLineItems[i].quoteLineItem.Discount = 0.00;
               quoteLineItems[i].quoteLineItem.Discount_Approved__c = false;
            }

        }

    }
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason why you have a nested for loop here? You mention that you want to update a single `QuoteLineItem`, but what if more than one `QuoteLineItem` has your `Promo__c` field checked?

Comment: @DerekF Sorry please ignore nested for loop.. If there are more than one QuoteLineItem with PROMO__C is checked then only those quoteLineItem should be updated ... and if we uncheck PROMO then the value in **Discount** field should also disappear

Comment: @DerekF For example, If I have the same quoteLineItem in the picture twice. And if uncheck/check the promo in one of the quoteLineItem then only that quoteLineItem's **Discount** should put in the value 20/disappear..

Comment: Avoid nested for loop here, Instead of updating the same list again try to add the list to another which you can update and omit the else part having Discount as 0.0 and Discount Approved as false by default.

Comment: @C.Praveenkumar Could you help me out in suggested case .. How can I do it

Answer (score 0):

By default set the Discount as 0.0 & Approved as false(hope it suffices the condition this way)

```
        public PageReference UpdatePromo() {   
        NewList = new List<quotelineitem>();
            for (integer i = 0; i <= quoteLineItems.size(); i++) {
                    if (quoteLineItems[i].Promo__c == true && quoteLineItems[i].Product_Code__c == 'LIC-OPTZ-01') {
                        quoteLineItems[i].Discount = 20.00;
                        quoteLineItems[i].Discount_Approved__c = true;
                        NewList.add(quoteLineItems[i]); // You can update this NewList
                    } 
            } 
            IF(NewList.size() > 0){
               Update NewList;
            }
       }
```